# Host header (SERVER:) and URL Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to hide the IIS version in my web server response. I am trying to do this via [URLRewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) for my website.

My web.config looks like so:

```
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="RewriteServerSoftware" stopProcessing="true">
                <match serverVariable="SERVER_SOFTWARE" pattern="." />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="MyServer" replace="true" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

This however does not seem to remove the value of `Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0`. What might I be missing?

My environment is Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.0, hosting an ASP.NET website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct server variable name is: **RESPONSE_Server** which follows the RESPONSE_*headername* format.

So your config should be:

```
   <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="RewriteServerSoftware" stopProcessing="true">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="MyServer" replace="true" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

One additional thing to note is that if you're using IIS 10.0 you also might need to add the following to your web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

In my case with IIS 10.0 only using both **URL-Rewrite** and the **removeServerHeader** worked.

More Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/